# async in JavaScript - When to use await (and when to not) - 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression .ts(80007)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am seeing this issue a lot in my code and I've seen similar posts about it on here but they don't seem linked to my issue specifically, which makes me think I'm missing something somewhere.

The comment `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)` comes up (as an example case) in the async method below...

```
    /**
     * Deletes the account for the currently logged in user.
     */
    async deleteAccount() {
        Logger.log('Deleting the currently logged in user', 'Auth')

        const service = ServiceFactory.profile()
        const operationState = await service.deleteUser()

        if (!operationState.succeeded)
            operationState.throw()
    },
```

Dropping through the stack, this calls through as follows to this method in the `ProfileService` class which is returned above in `ServiceFactory.profile()`...

```
    /**
     * Deletes a user.
     * @returns {ServiceOperation} The operation result.
     * @memberof ProfileService
     */
    async deleteUser() {
        const operationState = new ServiceOperation('Delete User', true)
        const url = `${ this.baseUrl }?SchemeId=${ this.schemeId }`
        Logger.log(url, 'Request [DELETE]')

        try {
            return this.processResponse(await Axios.delete(url), operationState, 'deleteUser')
        } catch (err) {
            return this.failOperation(err, operationState, 'deleteUser')
        }
    }
```

The issue seems related to the `processResponse` method on the base class that transforms my JSON responses from my back end into `ServiceOperation` classes which tracks running state, success, merges multiple results and transforms different types of error responses to be consistent for the app to handle - the code for which is largely irrelevant to add here...

```
    /**
     * Handles a succesfull data changing operation and processes the response safely.
     *
     * @param {Object} response The service response.
     * @param {ServiceOperation} operationState
     * @param {string} [methodName='?'] The name of the calling method.
     * @returns {ServiceOperation} The modified operation state.
     *
     * @memberof Service
     */
    processResponse(response, operationState, methodName = '?') {
        if (response.data !== false && !response.data || response.data == null) {
            operationState.complete(true)
        } else {
            operationState.complete(true, response.data)
        }
            Logger.logObject(response, `Operation completed [${ methodName }]`, this.loggingCategory)

        return operationState
    }
```

`failOperation` is simply `processResponse` fail call method...

```
    /**
     * Handles a failed operation.
     *
     * @param {Error} error
     * @param {ServiceOperation} operationState
     * @param {string} [methodName='?'] The name of the calling method.
     * @returns {ServiceOperation} The modified operation state.
     *
     * @memberof Service
     */
    failOperation(error, operationState, methodName = '?') {
        operationState.fail(error)
        Logger.logObject(operationState, `Data service failed [${ methodName }]`, this.loggingCategory)
        return operationState
    }
```

Both of the above methods are part of the `Service` class which is extended to form the `ProfileService` class earlier on that contains the `deleteUser` function (The `Service` class acts as a base class for each of the service classes in the app.

Where I'm a bit confused here is that `processResponse` isn't `async` (and doesn't need to be). The awaited call is awaited in the method that calls it. Is this just a case of the editor not picking it up or, as I suspect, is it that I'm losing the underlying promise when I process the data - If that's the case how can I get the promise to surface up for the method result that `processResponse` needs?

`processResponse` is a generic method that handles all the service method results I have in my app so merging the methods isn't viable. I've considered making `processResponse` itself `async` and using `await` on it but that seems logically like it would do absolutely nothing as there is nothing to really await.

Functionally the app code seems to be working fine so I'm loathe to start pulling it apart at this level until I understand exactly why it's moaning.

**EXTRA (but probably irrelevant) INFO**

This is the definition of the `ServiceOperation` class that the `Service` class and it's derivatives make use of. This is for completion only and is largely irrelevant.

```
/**
 * Defines an operation performed through a service.
 *
 * @export
 * @class ServiceOperation
 */
export default class ServiceOperation {

    /**
     *Creates an instance of ServiceOperation.
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {boolean} [started=false]
     * @memberof ServiceOperation
     */
    constructor(name, started = false) {
        this.name = name
        this.running = started
        this.completed = false
        this.succeeded = false
    }

    /**
     * Completes a service operation.
     *
     * @param {boolean} succeeded
     * @param {object} data Any data or error info returned
     * @returns {ServiceOperation} itself.
     * @memberof ServiceOperation
     */
    complete(succeeded, data) {
        this.running = false
        this.completed = true
        this.succeeded = succeeded

        if (data !== undefined && data !== null || this.data !== undefined && this.data !== null)
            this.data = data

        return this
    }

    /**
     * Fails a service operation.
     *
     * @param {string} error An error
     * @returns {ServiceOperation} itself.
     * @memberof ServiceOperation
     */
    fail(error) {
        this.complete(false)

        if (error && error.response && error.response.data) {
            this.data = error.response.data
            this.errorObject = error
            this.error = error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
            this.errorObject.message = this.error
        } else {
            this.error = error && error.message ? error.message : error
            this.errorObject = error
        }

        return this
    }

    /**
     * Throws the wrapped error object back for interrogation.
     *
     * @memberof ServiceOperation
     */
    throw() {
        if (this.errorObject)
            throw this.errorObject
        else if (this.error)
            throw new Error(this.error)
        else
            throw new Error('Service Operation error')
    }

    /**
     * Merges another operation into this one, updating it's info.
     *
     * @param {ServiceOperation} operation
     * @param {boolean} includeData If not set then the data item will be eradicated if it is present.
     * @memberof ServiceOperation
     */
    updateMergeFrom(operation, includeData = false) {
        this.running = operation.running
        this.completed = operation.completed
        this.succeeded = operation.succeeded

        if (!includeData && this.data)
            delete this.data
        else if (includeData && operation.data)
            this.data = operation.data


        if (operation.stillPending !== undefined)
            this.stillPending = operation.stillPending

        if (!this.error && operation.error)
            this.error = operation.error
    }

    /**
     * Generates an immediately completed operation.
     *
     * @static
     * @type {ServiceOperation}
     * @memberof ServiceOperation
     */
    static get immediate() {
        return new ServiceOperation('Immediate').complete(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `service.forgotPassword` return a promise? If it doesn't, then `await`-ing it is mostly superfluous. I'm not sure how your three pieces of code link up.

Comment: Also, I find it a bit strange that apparently `forgottenPassword` calls eventually calls `deleteUser`. Doesn't seem correct from general perspective.

Comment: async/await are just keywords for Promises syntax sugar. Does `service.forgotPassword` return a promise?

Comment: Ah - seems I'm suffering from Copy / Paste blindness - oh dear...

Comment: Updated to replace `forgottenPassword` with `deleteUser` - I have many methods with the same issue, hence why I think `processResponse` is the issue in some way.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error message, on the `const operationState = await service.deleteUser()` line? Can you confirm the compiler infers the type of that method call correctly (returning a promise)?

Comment: "*I've considered making `processResponse` itself `async`*" - no, don't do that. As you say, it doesn't do anything asynchronous, it is and should be synchronous. The asynchronous part is the `await Axios.delete(url)` in `deleteUser`, `processResponse` is unrelated to this.

Comment: @Bergi - I agree. The warning appears on "await service.deleteUser() - To me this should be awaited due to the await on the Axios call, but the compiler disagrees with me.

Comment: Is this a Typescript compiler warning, an eslint warning, or a typescript-eslint warning?

Comment: @KeithJackson What type does the compiler infer for the expression `service.deleteUser()`? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @Bergi - I don't really know. VSCode is moaning at me and I don't understand why. From everything I can see there shouldn't be any problems here (and the code works).  `service.deleteUser()` returns a `ServiceOperation` object. This is ES6 JavaScript. I can't create a reproducible example in this case without invalidating my question. It's quite possible that the warning is incorrect and can be safely ignored.

Comment: @KeithJackson "*`Service.deleteUser()` returns a `ServiceOperation` object.*" - ah, but that's wrong. It actually does return a `Promise<ServiceOperation>`, since it's an `async` function. I think you need to change the `@returns {ServiceOperation}` - and really, that's where the compiler should be complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this digging through this article...

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34508

This seems to be a warning generated by the TypeScript compiler (although my project isn't even using TypeScript so - {shrug})

In order to make it go away you need to edit your JSDoc entry as follows...

```
    /**
     * Deletes a user.
     * @returns {ServiceOperation} The operation result.
     * @memberof ProfileService
     */
    async deleteUser() { }
```

becomes

```
    /**
     * Deletes a user.
     * @returns {Promise<ServiceOperation>} The operation result.
     * @memberof ProfileService
     */
    async deleteUser() { }
```

Thanks to @Bergi for getting my brain to look in the right place.

Comment: JSDoc provides @async keyword but the TS compiler continue to warn.

Comment: According to the docs I'm not sure that adding @async achieves much: "In general, you do not need to use this tag, because JSDoc automatically detects asynchronous functions and identifies them in the generated documentation. However, if you are writing a virtual comment for an asynchronous function that does not appear in your code, you can use this tag to tell JSDoc that the function is asynchronous."